# QuickBlox Chat history

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I have saved the chat history by using following code in javascript:

```
   var message = {
        body: text,
        type: 'chat',
        extension: {
            nick: chatUser.login,
            save_to_history: 1
        }
    };
```

Now my problem is how can I get the whole chat history of two users in my chat window?

Answer (score 0):

To get a chat history for particular dialog use this request, You must have use dialog id of private dialog.

```
var dialogId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var params = {chat_dialog_id: dialogId, sort_desc: 'date_sent', limit: 100, skip: 0};
QB.chat.message.list(params, function(err, messages) {
  if (messages) {

  }else{
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Shashank If I solved your problem please accept the answer.